# Dartium displays blank page

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dartium

my Dartium web browser suddenly stopped displaying the content of Polymer application. Even the basic dart-polymer template project (that reversing of text) is not displayed. If you move the cursor to the position of a input box, it changes shape accordingly. Chrome works well.

I can't even remember the action which lead to this. Does Dartium perform auto updates? Yesterday it worked well, then I put the computer to sleep and came today and it doesn't work. I've tried to restart, reinstall etc. Hopeless...

Thanks for ideas

Rene

Comment: Hmm, very odd. I experienced this as well in the past hour. For me, updating Dart Editor fixed the issue (Help-> About Dart Editor).

Comment: Hey man, you are great. This solved the issue. Write it as the answer please so I can give you your kudos.

Comment: Done. I'm glad that it fixed it for you. I'm curious why this is happening though.

Comment: Dartium expires after a 12 weeks https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer According to your link the expiration only happens after a year? Also, this just happened again to me yesterday, which is only 6 weeks from the last time it happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem. Updating Dart Editor fixed the issue (under Help -> About Dart Editor).

Comment: I have this issue marked fixed in my head already since a while but people using stable might not have received the fixed version yet. Thanks for reminding me :)