# Dart editor debugger is not working

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dartium

Is just nor working, it Works if I run the proyect as JavaScript but not if a run it on Dartium, I removed all the extensions from Chrome, I reinstalled Dart and I still have the same problem.

Edit: I get this exception in the editor:

ReferenceError: fill most visited is not defined [id=1]

Dart Editor version 1.8.5.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.8.5
Window 8.1 64

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684928/dartium-displays-blank-page Is it the same issue?

Comment: What Dart version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed the problem deleting the folder AppData\Local\Google\Chrome, now is working, thanks.